# Menu items after burger button too close to burger

Tags: javascript, html, css

In mobile/tablet mode, I have a burger button that when I click on, menu items appear beneath it.

The appearing menu items are **too close** to the burger, causing a UX problem.

Given I need them to be **even more beneath**, I tried:

```
#burger {margin-bottom: 20px}
media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #burger {margin-bottom: 0}
}
```

this isn't good as it **enlarges** the entire menu area (`#menu-primary`). Targeting menu items themselves also does that...

[You could see the problem live in my site](http://integrative-massage.co.il) when surfing in mobile/tablet mode.

How will you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could target the first child in the list items like:

```
.menu li:first-child {
margin-top: 20px;
}
```

if you don't want the size of the menu bar to increase you could remove the padding here. I have removed the 20px and changed it to zero.

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
.elementor-14 .elementor-element.elementor-element-49f59133 {
padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Or set a max-height to the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure i understand right but i thing you want to vertical align the compressed menu. Please try this code and tell me if this solves your problem

```
.elementor-element.elementor-element-7955b736.elementor-widget.elementor-widget-wp-widget-nav_menu {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
}
```

i notice there ir a 'bottom' padding of 20px, here i am telling the hamburger options to move 10px bottom to look like perfectly centered